# Simulate cellular network's behaviour on Eclipse emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, gsm, cellular-network, umts

Is there any way to simulate the behaviour of a cellular mobile network (GSM/UMTS) in the Eclipse Android emulator?

More specifically: I want to develop an app to show information about the network, such as coverage level, parameters of neighbouring cells etc, as provided by the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and other related classes. I would like to do as much debugging as possible with the emulator, before testing in an actual phone.

For that I would need the emulated phone to "see" a functioning cellular network, with its protocols and parameters. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  As you probably know, the documentation is silent.  Is there a default configured?

Comment: @SList I haven't found anything. In fact I haven't actually tried the emulator yet. If I find something I'll post an answer here. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulator doesn't give you the option of setting that things. I have developed a toy app for showing network parameters and the only way I found was using a real phone.

By the way, not all phones implement all methods of Android's API, so you will find that some parameters will not be shown. And also many parameters are not available from API and you will need to get them throw AT commands (you will need a rooted device)

Comment: Hey, is that app of yours available? I would be interesting to see its source code, if that's public

Comment: Indeed I was developing it now. I have planned to released it yeah. Are you interested?

Comment: I would be interested in the app. And also in the source code if you plan to make it public. I could give my some ideas for my app

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I realize this question is two years old, but since this question received a slight edit from its original author 5 minutes ago and so got bumped back up to the front of the site, I am assuming that he may still be looking for an answer.*

Yes, AT&T provides such a free tool to simulate and analyze different network conditions to a certain extent. And it can be used in conjunction with Eclipse ADT, Android Studio, or something else entirely. So it's not tied to any particular IDE.

http://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer

That being said, I have no idea if it will give you any cell tower related meta data.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't seem to really emulate the network, does it? What I'd like is to have Eclipse ADT's emulated phone "see" a functioning network, with all its actual parameters such as coverage level, neighbour lists, channel configuration etc

Comment: No unfortunately, it doesn't go that far.